# Solving system of differential equations using matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

Solve the system of 51 differential equations: 
$$\frac{du_1}{dt}=0$$
$$\frac{du_k}{dt}=100(u_{k+1}-2u_k+u_{k-1})$$
$$\frac{du_{51}}{dt}=0$$

with initial condition $$u_k=\frac{k-1}{10}$$
from $t=0$ to $t=10$

I know I need to use backwards euler to solve the system since that is what we are studying. Also I must use successive over relaxation scheme to solve the matrix. 
To begin using backwards euler i know $$\frac{u_k^{n+1}-u_k^n}{dt}=\frac{du_k^{n+1}}{dt}$$
and the apply that to the system, but coding this into matlab is where i am stuck.

Comment: It seems the solution is constant in time, all time derivatives are zero as the second order divided difference of a linear function is zero. You do not need to compute anything for these conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the system matrix

```
D = 51
A = -2*diag(ones(D-2,1))+diag(ones(D-3,1),1)+diag(ones(D-3,1),-1)
A = 100*A
b = zeros(D-2,1)
b(1)=100*u0(1)
b(D-2)=100*u0(D)
```

Then your ODE system is just $\dot u = Au+b$. Solving the implicit Euler step requires to solve $$u^{n+1}+dt·A·u^{n+1} = u^n-dt·b.$$

Comment: It may not be wise to construct a *dense* matrix of the system and apply SOR later.

Comment: In dimension 50 and to get a start at getting any results at all, it is fully acceptable to use a dense matrix. If the subdivisions get finer and the dimension higher, one needs to be more efficient, but then one would not use an Euler method.